# Last selected value on Excel auto filter dropdown box

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-office

I have noticed a strange behavior when I creating a Workbook with auto filter column on Excel XP.

Normally, the last field I had auto filtered is checked on drop down:

[image: Example with expected result]

But when I create a workbook via an Access VBA script, I simple do not have this behavior:

[image: Example not working]

The code used to generate that workbook is:

```
Public Function exportToXLS(tableName, controlField)
    [...]

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, queryName, pathWorkbook, True

    [...]
End Function
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett it is an Access VBA script, sorry for not mentioned that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging around and asking to my work colleagues, I find out that to get this behavior the column must be in number-type format.

Inserting a text to columns in that row to ensure that is in number format I have solved my problem.

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```