# Filter to show Last Selected Option Excel

Tags: excel, filter

I am using Microsoft Office LTSC professional plus 2021.

I have a problem with filter. I have a long list of different products, so I use filter to select 1 product at a time. Since I have over 100 positions, I need to scroll down each time when I use filter window.
The problem is that whenever I open filter window, it shows from the 1st option, not from the last selected option(image provided).  I need the filter window to show me from the last selected option.

Please, provide step-by-step guide, I am not so good at computer-stuff.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understood properly but Filter window works that way. It will always show all **unique** options available, with a checkbox false/true to show/not show that value in the data range. As far as I know, what you want it's not possible in the same column.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not possible? In this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834897/last-selected-value-on-excel-auto-filter-dropdown-box?newreg=fa64aa42efe745958b23c8babdedefbc) the one who asked question was able to do that.

Comment: In that thread those are dropdowns lists, not filter windows.